# Best practise to remove stale documents in elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

I have a django app that pushes models into elasticsearch. I have a post signal to update after save but want to write a batch command that is updating all documents.

Within this process I want to remove documents that became stale (e.g. set inactive, got deleted etc in the database).

I started with something like this:

- update all documents and store the updated / created ids.
- create one gigantic exclude-query
- delete all documents that are matching

Something like this:

```
for i in updated_ids:
    q = Q('match', **{'id': i})
    f = f | q if f else q
queryset = dt.search().query(Bool(filter=[~Q(f)]))
for stale in queryset.scan():
    stale.delete()
```

But the query becomes to long and that fails.

I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

I use elasticsearch-dsl upon elasticsearch.py. Django-Haystack is not an option.

Comment: why updating all document, you mean to say that even with single document update, you do the bulk update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now doing it like that:

```
for dt, updated_ids in self.updated.items():
   existing_ids_in_index = [d.id for d in dt.search().scan()]
   stale_ids = list(set(existing_ids_in_index) - set(updated_ids))
   for stale_id in stale_ids:
       dt.find_one('id', stale_id).delete()
   print("... {}: Removed {}.".format(dt.get_model().__name__, len(stale_ids)))
```

I could further optimize this with a `delete_by_query` but I'm unsure about the details.

Answer (score 1):

In the `master` branch (to be released soon, you can just do `Search().delete()` to invoke the `delete_by_query` API.

Comment: Invoke on a queryset?

Comment: `delete` is a new method on the `Search` object.

Comment: But how do I pass the query / limit the set of things to be deleted?

Comment: just add `queryset.delete()` instead of your second `for` loop and it should work fine - the `Search` object (which you call queryset) already contains the queries that limit the documents to be deleted